# Not able to get total count in elastic search php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I am integrating elastic search in PHP + Mysql.

As far as I know, elastic search only returns 10 records by default.

Below is my search query.

```
 $params = [
            'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
            'type'  => $this->client->getType(),

            //"scroll" => "1m",

            'body'  => [
            "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                              "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => 'samsung'
                          ]
                     ],
                     [
                          "term"=> ["cat_type_id"=>1]
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
            ],
       ]; 
 $query  = $client->search($params);


    //return  array($this->extractResult($query),$this->extractResult($query1));
    return  $this->extractResult($query);
```

Above query returning 2000+ records in mysql but elastic search giving 10. I can put 'size upto 1000' in elastic search but that won't fill requirement. How do I get count of total records in elastic search. I want to get count for pagination in php.

Comment: I don't know how the php Elasticsearch library works, but Elasticsearch returns a json object with the field `hits`, which is an object with fields `total` and `hits`, where the inner `hits` is the array of results, and `total` is the total count of matching documents.